# Where do I get password for new TYPO3 installation?

Tags: typo3

I have installed typo3wininstaller on Windows 7. During installation no password was asked to be set. When I try to login to the backend, I am asked for a password. I am stuck. I tried to brouwse the TYPO3 user forums but was not able to get any help.
Any help to resolve this will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new user by logging into install tool on the URL: www.yoursitename.tld/typo3/install

All you have to do is create a file named: ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL in your typo3conf folder. The default password should be "joh316", if it doesn't work, you can just copy the hash you get from error message into typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php. I am gonna assume you are using the 7.6 version or later, then you will find it under Important actions on the bottom: Create backend administrator user.

Source: https://wiki.typo3.org/FAQ/Reset_admin_password

Comment: thanks @spisiak, let me work with what you have given me then I will give feedback later

Comment: The 'default' password "joh316" does only belong to outdated versions of TYPO3 and should not be valid any more for any new installation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will get a lot of problems. As far as I found is typo3wininstaller at best a Version 4.7 of TYPO3 which is much **outdated**.
you should start with a currently supported version. at the moment there is still available 6.2 LTS, but only supported until spring next year.
Better would be **7.6 LTS** or the newest versions from **8**.
The available version can be found here: https://get.typo3.org/

If you want a ready to use server you can look for ready to use virtual machines which can be installed with e.g. docker. But have an eye on the installed version.

As from version 7 you copy/unpack the sources and every try to access the website will tell you, that you need to install and configure TYPO3. You will be told to create files on the webserver to be sure that you are the owner of the server and in the install-process a first BackEnd user is created. The password of this user also is used to access the install-tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use this installer. As you can read under the 'About'-Section of the download-page you install TYPO3 4.7 - Which is outdated.

You should really take a newer version of TYPO3 like 7.6.x if you really want to develop a new project.

You can take a closer look here:

http://typo3worx.eu/2016/01/14-local-development-setups-for-typo3/

You will find informations about how to setup a dev-environment on your local computer.

If you still decide to use this version you can get access with the installtool to create a new Backenduser.

You should follow these steps:

1. go to the following url
   your-local.install/typo3/install
2. try joh316 as password

If this password fails, you will be told so and a hash of the password you just tried will be shown.

3. go to the folder typo3conf and look for the file localconf.php (Not as mentioned above LocalConfiguration.php which was (at least i think so) introduced in TYPO3 6.x Versions) and open it. In there should be a

   $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['installToolPassword']

Simply replace the hash with the one shown with the wrong password. 
Then you should be able to use the password and it should work (joh316 in this case)

Now you should be able to access the Installtool. 
Under Database Analyser scroll down to the bottom of the page and klick "Create 'admin' user" and choose a name and a password.

Now you can use this to login.

Comment: Thanks all, the assistance was very useful. I uninstalled Typo3wininstaller and installed TYPO3_src-7.6.11 and it worked fine logging onto the backend. Thank you very uch for all the efforts and time.